# parquet-tools cat command returns "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: parquet

I installed `parquet-tools` CLI.
When running `parquet-tools cat --debug -j` on whatever .parquet file it returns the Java error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2823)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2818)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2684)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.build(ParquetReader.java:299)
    at org.apache.parquet.tools.command.CatCommand.execute(CatCommand.java:82)
    at org.apache.parquet.tools.Main.main(Main.java:223)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3410)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1883)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I installed `parquet-tools` using Homebrew on MacOS.
I've Java SDK version 12:

```
java version "12" 2019-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12+33)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

This error only happens with Java 12. Parquet officially only supports Java 8, but Java 11 seems to work as well.

Comment: Java 10 didn't work for me, needed to switch to 8. To switch java versions on OSX for the current bash session: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` to see the java versions and then `export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_232` with the output of first command (part before the comma)